# How to convert a labview image type to opencv image type (or Mat)?

Tags: c++, opencv, labview

I'm using LabView to acquire an image from a usb camera and then I want to process this image using openCV functions through a dll file (which is used in call function VI). Now I want to convert the image format that Labview produce to process it with opencv. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "IMAQ GetImagePixelPtr" to get the pointer on the image in LabView.

In the dll, you should be able to get it like this :

```
    int function(unsigned __int8 *LVImagePointer, int lineWidth, int height, int width)
    {
        Mat image(height, width, CV_8UC1, LVImagePointer, lineWidth);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Vivien , opencv didn't create the image again. The output is black and white corrupted image :(

Comment: Is your image Black and white ?
If no, you can try : 

`Mat temp(height, width, CV_8UC4, LVImagePtr, 4 * lineWidth);`

Comment: It's an RGB image, I tried the last modification you added still I get a corrupted image.

Comment: in the call function VI, do you these params for the image pointer :

`Type : numeric`
`data type : unsigned 32 bits integer`
`pass : value`

and convert the output of "IMAQ GetImagePixelPtr" to a U32 before wiring it ?

Comment: why to declare the pointer as U32 where in the dll function declaration it's U8? and what do you mean by converting the output of "IMAQ GetImagePixelPtr" to a U32 ? I have set the "image type" in the "IMAQ create" to RGB (U32).

Comment: and also if I want to bring the image back to labview , will it be done in the same way of bringing back the image pointer params?

Comment: you're using a pointer to the image data, so if you modify Mat image in openCV, it will modify the image in labVIEW.

Comment: After applying your method , I want to get this image as output http://hpics.li/f7e4325,,, instead I get this http://hpics.li/3000087.

Comment: do you modify the Mat image you used to pass your image in the DLL code or create another one?

Comment: I took that image I created from the labview parameters and pass it to another Mat to do processing. I guess the way you mentioned before won't work !   
For example:
 `Mat src(height, width, CV_8UC4, LVImagePointer, 4*lineWidth);`
 `Mat blured;`
 `GaussianBlur( src, blured, Size(5,5),3,3 );`

Comment: It should work if you add : `blured.copyTo(src);` after your GaussianBlur

Comment: I tried to do this at the end of my opencv code; copy the final binary image to src , however I get the same results. Am I doing it wrong in my opencv code? considering the final result is a binary black and red image?

Comment: Would it be helpful if you have a look at the opencv code?

Comment: Yes, that would help ;)

Comment: Can you provide me with your email it seems that I can't paste the whole program here.

Comment: I've edited it, please look at it as soon as you can, so I delete it later :)

Comment: Also, is it possible that the while loop in LV is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using any of the available toolkits. Say, this one: https://www.ehe-lab.com/OpenCV_Wrapper.html

Comment: I'm using Labview 2014 and it not listed in the labview versions menu in the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I found it is easy to use `IMAQ ImageToArray` for `IMAGE`and `IMAQ GetImageSize` for `IMAGE_HEIGHT` and `IMAGE_WIDTH` and pass these to the DLL. They are called this way:

```
cv::Mat src = cv::Mat(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, CV_8UC1, IMAGE);
```

It has the advantage that all operations on `src`can be seen in Labview by converting the array you get out of the DLL back to an image.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that it is complicated to keep the memory from leaking. I suggest you use a toolkit: http://ms-consultants.de/index.php/software/msc-image-processing/37-msc-image-processing-eng

They also offer to implement new functions if you need more.